# RStudio - Error in template_dfa: object '_htmltools_template_dfa' not found when attempting to Run Document

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

I have a .rmd that is a `flexdashboard` Shiny app. It used to work about an hour ago. Header is:

```
---
title: "my dashboard"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    logo: logo-only-TINY.jpg
    favicon: logo-only-TINY.jpg
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

I originally had an issue with this .rmd with RStudio unable to connect to shinyapps.io from an SSL error. The recommendation from RStudio Community was to change the settings in Windows Defender Firewall to let RStudio communicate through the firewall, so I did that. Immediately afterwards (and I'm not sure if these are linked), my RStudio became unable to render any RMd documents at all.

When clicking on "Run Document" the following error appears in the RMarkdown tab in bottom left panel:

```
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4177
Warning: Error in template_dfa: object '_htmltools_template_dfa' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

Does anyone know what this means? I reinstalled the `htmltools` package, but think this is something different. Thanks for any help that anyone might have.

Comment: Hi, I got the similar error when I have installed 'plotly' library in R v 3.4.4. I have just updated the R to version 3.6.3 and updated all the existing packages. The error resolved. Good luck.

Comment: I finally resolved the issue by wiping R and RStudio off my machine & reinstalling both... but would still love to know what this was all about in case in happens again.

Comment: I just encountered this too, even have version control and have not changed my code at all.. I did also update plot.ly. Did you find any solutions? I've upgraded R studio and all my libraries.